# Custom Mendeley Style is malformed

Tags: cls, mendeley

I am trying to define a custom Mendeley style but when I run it through the CSL validator, it returns two errors. Since I am new to this and have limited coding experience, does someone have any idea how it can be fixed?
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kiwe.png)
The link to the style is below:
[link](http://csl.mendeley.com/styles/726793111/dji-style-2025)

I tried gpt on both errors but without success.